# How to make jQuery autocomplete work in all columns and for new child row of a table

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am implementing jQuery autocomplete in a website. I've already implemented autocomplete to display results from the current column for rows (works properly). But now I am trying to implement it to work for child rows as well. **It has to display results from the current column and from the set of child rows of the current row only.** I have problems with this. It works but only for the existing child rows in the first column. It doesn't work both for new child rows and for childrows in the 2nd, 3rd, etc. columns.

Can you help me, please? I want it to work for all columns and secondly for new rows as well, not only for existing rows.

**This is the method for subrows.**

```js
function handleSubPropertiesAutocomplete(model, subProps, dataRowsArr) {

    let subPropsSuggestions = [];

    for (let j = 0; j < subProps.length; j++) {
        if (!subProps[j].type === "STRING") {
            continue;
        }

        for (let k = 0; k < dataRowsArr.length; k++) {
            if (!dataRowsArr[k].hasOwnProperty(model.childrenProperty)) {
                continue;
            }

            var childEntries = (dataRowsArr[k])[model.childrenProperty];

            var parentRowClass = null;
            for (var l = 0; l < childEntries.length; l++) {
                subPropsSuggestions.push(childEntries[l].nodeName);
            }

            //Autocomplete for strings in a current child row
            $('.child_autocomplete_' + k + '_' + subProps[j].name).autocomplete(
                {
                    source: subPropsSuggestions
                }
            );

            //Autocomplete for strings in a new unsaved child row
            $('.child_autocomplete_undefined_' + subProps[j].name).autocomplete(
                {
                    source: subPropsSuggestions
                }
            );

            subPropsSuggestions = [];
        }
    }
}
```

**JSP for new row with string value:**

```html
{{else prop.type === 'STRING' }} {{if !$item.isMasterEditable}} {{if prop.name != $item.uniqueIdProperty && $item.isMasterChild && !$item.isChild}}
<div class="editable actual-value" contentEditable="false"></div>
{{else prop.name == $item.uniqueIdProperty && $item.isChild}}
<div class="editable actual-value" contentEditable="false"></div>
{{else $item.isChild}}
<input class="editable actual-value ${" child_autocomplete_ "+$item.parentRowNumber+'_'+prop.name}" contentEditable="true" value=$ {getValueFromCell($item, prop)}></input>
{{else}}
<input class="editable actual-value ${" autocomplete_ "+prop.name}" contentEditable="true" value=$ {getValueFromCell($item, prop)}></input>
{{/if}} {{else}} {{if !$item.isChild}}
<input class="editable actual-value ${" autocomplete_ "+prop.name}" contentEditable="true" value=$ {getValueFromCell($item, prop)}></input>
{{else}}
<input class="editable actual-value ${" child_autocomplete_ "+$item.parentRowNumber+'_'+prop.name}" contentEditable="true" value=$ {getValueFromCell($item, prop)}></input>
{{/if}} {{/if}}
```

**JSP for existing row with string values:**

```html
{{else prop.type === 'STRING' }}
    {{if !$item.isMasterEditable}}
     {{if prop.name != $item.uniqueIdProperty && $item.isMasterChild && !$item.isChild}}
      <div class="editable actual-value" contentEditable="false">${getValueFromCell($item, prop)}</div>
     {{else prop.name == $item.uniqueIdProperty && $item.isChild}}
      <div class="editable actual-value" contentEditable="false">${getValueFromCell($item, prop)}</div>
     {{else $item.isChild}}
         <input class="editable actual-value ${"child_autocomplete_"+$item.parentRowNumber+'_'+prop.name}" contentEditable="true" value = ${getValueFromCell($item, prop)}></input>
     {{else}}
      <input class="editable actual-value ${"autocomplete_"+prop.name}" contentEditable="true" value = ${getValueFromCell($item, prop)}></input>
     {{/if}}
    {{else}}
        {{if !$item.isChild}}
            <input class="editable actual-value ${"autocomplete_"+prop.name}" contentEditable="true" value = ${getValueFromCell($item, prop)}></input>
        {{else}}
            <input class="editable actual-value ${"child_autocomplete_"+$item.parentRowNumber+'_'+prop.name}" contentEditable="true" value = ${getValueFromCell($item, prop)}></input>
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
```

**This is the properly working method for parent rows:**

```js
function handlePropertiesAutocomplete(props, dataRowsArr) {
  let propsSuggestions = [];

  for (let p = 0; p < props.length; p++) {

    if (props[p].type === "STRING") {

      for (let r = 0; r < dataRowsArr.length; r++) {
        propsSuggestions.push(dataRowsArr[r][props[p].name])
      }
    }

    $('.autocomplete_' + props[p].name).autocomplete({
      source: propsSuggestions
    });

    propsSuggestions = [];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the method to work in all columns - the mistake was I took nodeName instead subProps[i].name.
So, subPropsSuggestions.push(childEntries[l].nodeName) has to become subPropsSuggestions.push(childEntries[l][subProps[i].name]);

But it doesn't work for new child rows yet.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works. The solution was:
 1. A whole new method

```js
function handleAddChildAutocomplete (e, subProps, model) {
 let suggestions = [];
 
 let newChild = e.currentTarget;
 let parentRowElement = $(newChild).parent().parent();
 let parentRowElementId = $(parentRowElement).attr('id');
 let parentRowIndexStart = parseInt(parentRowElementId.lastIndexOf('_')) + 1;
 let parentRowIndex = parentRowElementId.substring(parentRowIndexStart);
 let dataRowsArr = model.get('objects');
 
 let parentRow = dataRowsArr[parentRowIndex];
 let childEntries = parentRow[model.childrenProperty];
 
 for (let i = 0; i < subProps.length; i++) {
  if (!subProps[i].type === 'STRING') {
   continue;
  }
  
  for (let j = 0; j < childEntries.length; j++) {
   if (childEntries[j][subProps[i].name] != null) {
    suggestions.push(childEntries[j][subProps[i].name]);
   }
  }
  
  //Autocomplete for input in a new unsaved child row
  $('.child_autocomplete_undefined_' + subProps[i].name).autocomplete(
   {
    source: suggestions,
    minLength: 1
   });
  suggestions = [];
 }
}
```

2. Put he following in the method that invokes the method above:

```js
$(newChild).keypress(handleAddChildAutocomplete(e, subProps, model));
```